# Ansible - Create multiple config files using the same template in a role

Tags: ansible, devops, ansible-role

I have found a similar question: [Creating multiple times the same role, but with different items](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35154601/creating-multiple-times-the-same-role-but-with-different-items)
but I do not know how I can use it with the group_vars directory structure.

## My Question

How can I use a role with a template inside of it to create multiple config files with different names and values?  I also am using the group_vars directory which exists on the same level as the playbook I run with the hosts it runs.

Here is my current sample playbook

```
---
- hosts: emea-stg-web
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/ssh_user.yml
  remote_user: "{{ ssh_user }}"
  become_user: root

  roles:
    - nginx-install
    - php5.6-install
```

How can I have each "item" in a role use different variable values.  Such as a variable "name" can have ["test 1", "test 2", "test 3"] as it iterates through?  Can I then store these values in a file?

```
---
- hosts: emea-stg-web
  vars_files:
    - group_vars/ssh_user.yml
  remote_user: "{{ ssh_user }}"
  become_user: root

  roles:
    - nginx-install
      with_items:
      - test1
      - test2
      - test3
    - php5.6-install
```

Comment: Vars files from `group_vars` are automatically included per group membership. Other than that (obvious misuse), your question is completely unclear.

Comment: what do you mean by "per group membership"?

Comment: What I want to do is create multiple Nginx files on each host (in my system) for various URLs, and also that will have different parameters sent to the template file.  Your assumption of me not having been over the docs multiple times is incorrect.  However with that being said, I do see your point about the group_vars having membership to the corresponding group I create.  I am editing my question again to clear up items.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Have a look at the [`include_role` module](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/include_role_module.html) with the `vars_from` parameter:

```
tasks:
  - include_role:
      role: nginx-install
      vars_from: "{{ item }}"
    with_items:
      - vars_file1
      - vars_file2
```

And do not use `group_vars` directory for storing arbitrary vars files, it's intended to store vars files for host groups.

Comment: this is very helpful techraf.   Thank you.  Where would you advise to store my arbitrary vars files?  As in, what would make logical sense?